# Getting TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types int_const 1000000000000000000 and address payable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I am trying to use external modifier however I getting error as below code.

```
  {   
    require(block.timestamp < start + buyPeriod);
    require(1 ether == msg.sender);<--- error got here
    require(_tickets[msg.sender] == 0);
    _tickets[msg.sender] = hash;
    _entries.push(msg.sender);
    return true;
    }  
Getting error as Getting TypeError: Operator == not compatible with 
types int_const 1000000000000000000 and address payable.
```

Could anyone can help me to fixed it?

Comment: `1 ether == msg.sender`? What the hell does that even mean??? (pardon my French).

Comment: Sorry @ goodvibration, Its my bad Its should be msg.value. I need some sleep as I am doing silly mistake in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant `msg.value` instead of `msg.sender`? You're currently comparing a number (1 ether) to the address of the account that called your function.

If you meant to be checking the amount of ether that was sent in the transaction, you want `msg.value`.