# Getting error as Member "balance" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Lottery

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I am trying one Lottery contract in that I am using one function which give me error.

```
 function pickAWinner() public restricted {
    require(this.balance >= 10 ether);
    uint index = random() % players.length;
    players[index].transfer(this.balance);
    players = new address[](0);
  }
```

Getting below error, Below error I am getting other contract also as *"Member "balance" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract"* I think there is issue with 'balance' keyword. however I Unable to fixed it.

```
  Error:-TypeError: Member "balance" not found or not visible after           
  argument-dependent lookup in contract Lottery. Use 
  "address(this).balance" to access this address member.
    require(this.balance >= 10 ether);
            ^----------^
```

How can I fixed it?

Comment: The error message tells you "use address(this).balance to access this address member." Is there a reason you haven't tried following these instructions? @goodvibration's answer is basically a rephrasing of the error message.

Comment: sorry @RoscoKalis, I have more careful to error massage, Next time I will thanks for notify me.

Comment: Mooi worries, good luck developing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `this.balance` to `address(this).balance`.

Comment: BTW, thought you said [you needed to get some sleep](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/66207/16043).

Comment: yes@goodvibration, however when I am trying sleep I can't because of this error and incomplete work once I get understand this issues then I can sleep.

Comment: Again thanks@goodvibration for reply on this, because of this community I am learning now. solidity community really helpful and amazing, I hope I could also give to this community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
transfer_address.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

where transfer_address is the address of the account to which you want to transfer all ETH from the current contract